# Why does gethostbyaddr(gethostname()) return my IPv6 IP?

Tags: python, sockets, ip-address, ipv6, ipv4

I'm working on making a simple server application with python, and I'm trying to get the IP to bind the listening socket to. An example I looked at uses this:

```
HOST = gethostbyaddr(gethostname())
```

With a little more processing after this, it should give me just the host IP as a string. This should return the IPv4 address. But when I run this code, it returns my IPv6 address. Why does it do this and how can I get my IPv4 address?

If its relevant, I'm using windows vista and python 2.5

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Getting your IP address is harder than you might think.

Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/270745/how-do-i-determine-all-of-my-ip-addresses-when-i-have-multiple-nics#274644) I gave for the one reliable way I've found.

Here's what the answer says in case you don't like clicking on things:

Use the [`netifaces`](http://alastairs-place.net/netifaces/) module.  Because networking is complex, using netifaces can be a little tricky, but here's how to do what you want:

```
>>> import netifaces
>>> netifaces.interfaces()
['lo', 'eth0']
>>> netifaces.ifaddresses('eth0')
{17: [{'broadcast': 'ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff', 'addr': '00:11:2f:32:63:45'}], 2: [{'broadcast': '10.0.0.255', 'netmask': '255.255.255.0', 'addr': '10.0.0.2'}], 10: [{'netmask': 'ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff::', 'addr': 'fe80::211:2fff:fe32:6345%eth0'}]}
>>> for interface in netifaces.interfaces():
...   print netifaces.ifaddresses(interface)[netifaces.AF_INET]
...
[{'peer': '127.0.0.1', 'netmask': '255.0.0.0', 'addr': '127.0.0.1'}]
[{'broadcast': '10.0.0.255', 'netmask': '255.255.255.0', 'addr': '10.0.0.2'}]
>>> for interface in netifaces.interfaces():
...   for link in netifaces.ifaddresses(interface)[netifaces.AF_INET]:
...     print link['addr']
...
127.0.0.1
10.0.0.2
```

This can be made a little more readable like this:

```
from netifaces import interfaces, ifaddresses, AF_INET

def ip4_addresses():
    ip_list = []
    for interface in interfaces():
        for link in ifaddresses(interface)[AF_INET]:
            ip_list.append(link['addr'])
    return ip_list
```

If you want IPv6 addresses, use `AF_INET6` instead of `AF_INET`.  If you're wondering why `netifaces` uses lists and dictionaries all over the place, it's because a single computer can have multiple NICs, and each NIC can have multiple addresses, and each address has its own set of options.

Answer (score 5):

IPv6 is taking precedence over IPv4 as it's the newer family, it's generally what you want if your hostname is associated with multiple families.  You should be using [getaddrinfo](http://docs.python.org/library/socket.html#socket.getaddrinfo) for family independent resolution, here is an example,

```
import sys, socket;
host = socket.gethostname();
result = socket.getaddrinfo(host, None);
print "family:%i socktype:%i proto:%i canonname:%s sockaddr:%s"%result[0];
result = socket.getaddrinfo(host, None, socket.AF_INET);
print "family:%i socktype:%i proto:%i canonname:%s sockaddr:%s"%result[0];
result = socket.getaddrinfo(host, None, socket.AF_INET6);
print "family:%i socktype:%i proto:%i canonname:%s sockaddr:%s"%result[0];
```

Which on a dual-stack configured host gives me the following,

```
family:10 socktype:1 proto:6 canonname: sockaddr:('2002:dce8:d28e::31', 0, 0, 0)
family:2 socktype:1 proto:6 canonname: sockaddr:('10.6.28.31', 0)
family:10 socktype:1 proto:6 canonname: sockaddr:('2002:dce8:d28e::31', 0, 0, 0)
```

Answer (score 2):

[`gethostbyaddr()`](http://docs.python.org/library/socket.html#socket.gethostbyaddr) takes an IP address as a parameter, not a hostname, so I'm surprised it's working at all without throwing an exception.  If instead you meant [`gethostbyname()`](http://docs.python.org/library/socket.html#socket.gethostbyname), then your results are more surprising, since that function claims not to support IPv6.  [Harley's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/415407/why-does-gethostbyaddrgethostname-return-my-ipv6-ip#415417) explains how to correctly get your IP address.