# Python - Get localhost IP

Tags: python, sockets, ip-address

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Finding local IP addresses using Python's stdlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/166506/finding-local-ip-addresses-using-pythons-stdlib)

To get my localhost IP address I do `socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname())`. But it gives me the answer `127.0.0.1`.
If I do `an_existing_socket.getsockname()[0]` I get the answer `0.0.0.0`.

I need my 'real' ip address (for instance 192.168.x.x) to modify a configuration file. How could I get it?

Comment: @BigYellowCactus You're right, I'll look at these answers

Comment: @Germann Arlington This configuration file is destinated to be used on another host: **1). I update the conf file** with my IP and **2). I launch** remotely an appli that use this conf file. For several reasons, I can't have any control upon the remote host when the appli is launched.

Comment: @Vaïk Godard - in this case the best solution is to address it by name and let network DNS resolve it to the address.

Comment: The current duplicate link is to a slightly different question that adds "using Python's stdlib." If you can suffer an external package, [How do I determine all of my IP addresses when I have multiple NICs?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/270745/how-do-i-determine-all-of-my-ip-addresses-when-i-have-multiple-nics) might be more helpful.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I generally use this code:

```
import os
import socket

if os.name != "nt":
    import fcntl
    import struct

    def get_interface_ip(ifname):
        s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
        return socket.inet_ntoa(fcntl.ioctl(s.fileno(), 0x8915, struct.pack('256s',
                                ifname[:15]))[20:24])

def get_lan_ip():
    ip = socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname())
    if ip.startswith("127.") and os.name != "nt":
        interfaces = [
            "eth0",
            "eth1",
            "eth2",
            "wlan0",
            "wlan1",
            "wifi0",
            "ath0",
            "ath1",
            "ppp0",
            ]
        for ifname in interfaces:
            try:
                ip = get_interface_ip(ifname)
                break
            except IOError:
                pass
    return ip
```

I don't know it's origin, but it works on Linux/Windows.

**Edit:**

This code is [used](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1947766/142637) by [smerlin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/231717/smerlin) in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/166506/finding-local-ip-addresses-using-pythons-stdlib) stackoverflow question.

Comment: `fcntl` is not a standard python library.

Comment: and this is a much shorter solution: http://stackoverflow.com/a/25850698/210709

Comment: running out of the box, +1 :-)

Comment: Doesn't work on mac OS X Catalina.

Answer (score 19):

There is a nifty module you can use. Its called netifaces. Just do a pip install netifaces into a virtualenv for testing and try the following code:

```
import netifaces

interfaces = netifaces.interfaces()
for i in interfaces:
    if i == 'lo':
        continue
    iface = netifaces.ifaddresses(i).get(netifaces.AF_INET)
    if iface != None:
        for j in iface:
            print j['addr']
```

It all depends on your environment. If you only have one interface with one IP address attached to it, you can simply do:

```
netifaces.ifaddresses('eth0')[netifaces.AF_INET][0]['addr']
```

If you are behind a NAT and want to know your public IP address, you can use something like:

```
import urllib2

ret = urllib2.urlopen('https://icanhazip.com/')
print ret.read()
```

Hope this helps.