# Python: check whether a network interface is up

Tags: python, networking, ip, dhcp, network-interface

In Python, is there a way to detect whether a given **network interface** is **up**?

In my script, the user specifies a network interface, but I would like to make sure that the interface is up and has been assigned an IP address, before doing anything else.

I'm on **Linux** and I am **root**.

Comment: What OS? Does this script need to run on different OS's, or is it just one in particular?

Comment: Ops. Linux. ;) In the future I will extend this to OS X and Windows, but for now Linux will be enough

Comment: No worries :). http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11735821/python-get-localhost-ip/11736402 <-- have you seen this? The accepted answer works on linux. The netifaces module is portable and will work on the tested os's.

Comment: Wow, that library is awesome! It solved all my problems. Thanks!!

Comment: I AM ON LINUX and I AM ROOT sounds like this is my house ,i ll burn it if i have too!!!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As suggested by @Gabriel Samfira, I used `netifaces`. The following function returns True when an IP address is associated to a given interface.

```
def is_interface_up(interface):
    addr = netifaces.ifaddresses(interface)
    return netifaces.AF_INET in addr
```

The documentation is [here](https://github.com/raphdg/netifaces)

Comment: A useful check before calling the above function is: `if anInterface in netifaces.interfaces() #...`

Comment: Unfortunately, this does work only half for IPv6/AF_INET6: while an interface becomming RUNNING gets its LLA, when the same interface goes offline, the LLA still lives on.

Answer (score 15):

The interface can be configured with an IP address and not be up so the accepted answer is wrong. You actually need to check `/sys/class/net/<interface>/flags`. If the content is in the variable flags, `flags & 0x1` is whether the interface is up or not.

Depending on the application, the `/sys/class/net/<interface>/operstate` might be what you really want, but technically the interface could be up and the `operstate` down, e.g. when no cable is connected.

All of this is Linux-specific of course.

Comment: A warning: in Linux Mint 18.2, the Cinnamon Network Manager applet control to turn off a network adapter leaves it both UP and operational. It removes the IP address, though.

Answer (score 8):

Answer using [psutil](https://psutil.readthedocs.io/en/latest/):

```
import psutil
import socket

def check_interface(interface):
    interface_addrs = psutil.net_if_addrs().get(interface) or []
    return socket.AF_INET in [snicaddr.family for snicaddr in interface_addrs]
```

Answer (score 3):

With [pyroute2](https://github.com/svinota/pyroute2).IPRoute:

```
from pyroute2 import IPRoute
ip = IPRoute()
state = ip.get_links(ip.link_lookup(ifname='em1'))[0].get_attr('IFLA_OPERSTATE')
ip.close()
```

With [pyroute2](https://github.com/svinota/pyroute2).IPDB:

```
from pyroute2 import IPDB
ip = IPDB()
state = ip.interfaces.em1.operstate
ip.release()
```

Answer (score 2):

You can see the content of the file in `/sys/class/net/<interface>/operstate`. If the content is not `down` then the interface is up.

Answer (score 0):

If the question is about checking if the cable is conencted (FreeBSD);

```
[status for status in run.cmd(' /usr/local/bin/sudo ifconfig %s ' % interface).split("\t") if status.strip().startswith("status")][0].strip().endswith("active")
```

For this, no api support so far :( ...

Comment: That's a bit of an overkill if we can simply read `/sys/class/net/<interface>/operstate`...

Comment: on FreeBSD 11 `cat: /sys/class/net/em0/operstate: No such file or directory`

Comment: I see. Is  there an equivalent to `/sys/class/net`?

Comment: I could not see. I would love to know the equivalent in FreeBSD.