# Run python script upon connection to wifi

Tags: python, wifi, python-2.6

I'm trying to find a way to run a script in python that "listens" to wifi connection status and will execute a certain function that I made when the computer gets connected to wifi.

The function will connect to a server socket and send some information to it.

Does anyone have any idea how to implement this?

Thanks!

Comment: What operating system(s) do you want to support?

Comment: windows ,  I'm working on windows 7

Answer (score 0):

Checking the wifi connection status can be handled in a few ways (see [here for some options](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17680779/939586)). You can then poll that with a structure along the lines of:

```
while not done:
    if is_interface_up(interface):
       do_the_thing(interface)
    time.sleep(0.1)
```

If this is a more substantial application you might want to do this with an event driven architecture instead of a while loop---something along the lines of [Twisted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/twisted).