# Getting wrong local IP address in python

Tags: python, ip-address

My OS is Windows 8.1 and i have Windows 7 and linux debian installed in Vmware. In python (2.7) when i try to get local ip address it shows vmware's ip address(Win7) instead of Win8.1 ip address(picture)! What is the problem?
I have set vmware's network adapter to NAT.

Edit: The code i used: `socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname())`

[image]

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/27423915/3270800

Comment: Can you add your code in your question? Its difficult to see in picture

Comment: I'm sorry! I used `socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname())`

Comment: what ip are you trying to get?

Comment: My local ip address (192.168.1.2)

Comment: what does `socket.gethostname()` return?

Comment: My computer name ('DELL') does it matter?

Comment: I think the code is correct but i don't know why it returns vmware's local ip address instead of Windows ip address?

Comment: look at the first answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11735821/python-get-localhost-ip

Comment: @TanveerAlam, your answer in that question is an exact copy taken from the link I posted

Comment: @PadraicCunningham That's why i included in SO answer so that it would be easy to share with others. I have even shared the link in my answer.

Comment: @TanveerAlam, yes but I do think it is good practice to add a link to where you got the code from.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham I did added the link below please see my answer again.

Answer (score 1):

**try use this**

```
import socket

LocalIP = ''.join(socket.gethostbyname_ex(socket.gethostname())[2])

print(LocalIP)
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use this. 
That's when you have more than one IP on your machine, you manipulate the [0, 1] to pick the correct one.
In my case, it's the second one. That's why 1 but in yours its 0.

```
LocalIP = (socket.gethostbyname_ex(socket.gethostname())[2][1])
```

[Documentation for socket.gethostbyname_ex(hostname)](https://docs.python.org/2/library/socket.html#socket.gethostbyname_ex)