# server.listen() vs app.listen() Google Apple Engine

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, google-app-engine, socket.io

I have a NodeJS + Express application.

When running on localhost, I use

```js
const port = 3001;

server.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`App listening on port ${port}`);
});
```

When deploying to GAE, I use

```js
const port = process.env.PORT || 8080;

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`App listening on port ${port}`);
});
```

It was working fine until today, when I needed to implement Sockets.io on my application.

Sockets requires a server listening `server.listen()`, but GAE doesn't seem to accept this method, and only accepts `app.listen()` instead.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, these two methods of coding are fundamentally equivalent:

```
const server = http.createServer(app);
server.listen(port);
```

And:

```
const server = app.listen(port);
```

All, `app.listen()` does internally is  call `http.createServer(app)` and then call `server.listen()`.  So, `app.listen()` is just a shortcut.  Here's more on `app.listen()` [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70384927/what-does-the-listen-method-in-express-look-like/70386667#70386667).

If you need the server instance for use with socket.io, then just assign it like I show in `const server = app.listen(port);` and then use that `server` instance to pass to socket.io for it to share your http server.

---

Note, if you want to create an https server, then you have to do it the first way I show above (and pass the security credentials) because `app.listen()` does not create an https server.