# ImportError: No module named netifaces

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm trying to get the IP address and MAC address of my pc's network card by python. I got some code from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/270745/how-do-i-determine-all-of-my-ip-addresses-when-i-have-multiple-nics)

I create a proj "getip".
create "main.py". And I modify the code of "main.py" as follow

```
from netifaces import interfaces, ifaddresses, AF_INET

def ip4_addresses():
    ip_list = []
    for interface in interfaces():
        for link in ifaddresses(interface)[AF_INET]:
            ip_list.append(link['addr'])

    return ip_list

def main():
    print ip4_addresses()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

and I create "app.yaml"

```
application: getip
version: 1
runtime: python
api_version: 1

handlers:
- url: .*
  script: main.py
```

and when I run the main.py at console as "python main.py", I got the ip addresses.

and when I run as "dev_appserver.py getip", the server is setup. When I browse the page as localhost:8080, the web page is white screen and I got the following error at console.

> from netifaces import interfaces, ifaddresses, AF_INET
>
> ImportError: No module named netifaces

How can I solve the problem?

Comment: Does your appserver run the same Python binary? What does `head dev_appserver.py` tell you is used?

Comment: It looks like you are using Google App engine. Why?

Comment: @MartijnPieters, I got this **head: cannot open `dev_appserver.py' for reading: No such file or directory**

Comment: @ThuRa: Then use `head \`which dev_appserver.py\``; you have it on your path somewhere.

Comment: @glasslion, I'm newbie to Python.

Comment: @ThuRa, why do you create app.yaml and run dev_appserver.py getip? They are only available in Google App engine.

Comment: @MartijnPieters, **head: cannot open `which dev_appserver.py' for reading: No such file or directory**

Comment: @ThuRa: What platform are you running this on? And is this the Google Appserver?

Comment: @glasslion, according to this book http://www.oreillynet.com/pub/a/web-services/excerpts/9780596800697/run-google-app-linux.html

Comment: @MartijnPieters, Linux (Ubuntu 12.04). Yes, this is Google App Engine.

Comment: @ThuRa: It looks like you mistyped my command then; but if this is Google Appserver then the answer is simple; that server uses a *different* Python path.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to import modules in Google App Engine?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2710861/how-to-import-modules-in-google-app-engine)

Answer (score 10):

just install `netifaces`

`pip install netifaces` if you have pip installed, or download the source, unpack it run and `python setup.py install`

warning: this will install it globally on your system, so use caution, or use [virtualenv](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/virtualenv)

Answer (score 6):

If you are using **ubuntu**:

```
sudo apt install python3-netifaces
```

Answer (score 5):

Came here for the same question but in my case `pip install` would say that requirement is already satisfied. However:

`pip uninstall netifaces && pip install netifaces`

fixed it.

Leaving this here for posterity. Use `sudo` if you need to.

Comment: This lead me to my actual issue. I had netifaces installed multiple times. Tried to pip uninstall and it said `Not uninstalling netifaces at /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages, outside environment /usr`. Switched to root and did `apt remove python3-netifaces` then the pip works as expected

Answer (score 1):

Actually, the problem here is you must be root when installed with pip, or it will not install globally. Therefore would not be able to find the module unless in the same directory or path as the module directory

so you need this:

```
sudo pip install netifaces
```

or on windows install with an elevated command prompt!

Comment: You don't need an elevated command prompt to install packages on Windows.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you have installed `netifaces` in your local development environment. But Google App Engine does not recognize it.

If you run your script with `python main.py`, Python interpreter will look for your libraries in the PYTHONPATH. GAE does not follow that rule.

To install a library in GAE, usually you just need to put the library module directory in the root of your app path(whee the app.yaml is). But I don't think Google will allow you to install libraries that can get hardware information in their PaaS for security reasons.

Updates:

Becaue you just need a web server to output the result,  I recommend you to choose a simple, well documented, micro Python web framework, like [Flask](http://flask.pocoo.org/) or [bottle](http://bottlepy.org/docs/dev/).

Installation: 
`pip install Flask` or `easy_install Flask`

code:

```
from flask import Flask
from netifaces import interfaces, ifaddresses, AF_INET
app = Flask(__name__)

def ip4_addresses():
    ip_list = []
    for interface in interfaces():
        for link in ifaddresses(interface)[AF_INET]:
            ip_list.append(link['addr'])

    return ip_list

@app.route("/")
def main():
    return str(ip4_addresses())

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

Run: python main.py

Comment: your answer is nearly correct. Actually, I want to create an application for both win and Linux. But I'm a newbie to Python. I'm coming from web (LAMP) environment. That why, I don't know how to create an application by python. If you can, pls knowledge share to me.

Comment: If your want to learn/create a python web application, I suggest your choose some web frameworks like Flask (or bottle, Django), not Google App engine.

Comment: Thank @glasslion, I'll try one of them, may be Django. But I want to create a software application not web application.

Comment: I install Flask by your. And when I run python main.py, I got this **ImportError: No module named flask**.