# How to get the host's IP address using python?

Tags: python

I'm trying to get a host's ip address using this code:

```
import os
import socket
ip = socket.gethostbyname(os.environ['COMPUTERNAME'])
```

the problem is that this host has VMware installed and the IP I get with the code above is that belonging to VMware, and not to the host.
How can I fix this without uninstalling VMware? :P

Comment: First, there's not "the" IP address. A host can have several addresses at once. Next, what IP addresses do you expect? The ones of the client, the ones of the host, the ones of your DSL router, ...?

Comment: Do you mean *host* as in server, or *host* as in VM Host? Where are you running this? (VM Guest or VM Host?) Which IP address are you trying to get? (VM Guest or VM Host?)

Comment: @ThomasWeller I'm not sure the OP has a client in mind. Do you mean VM guest?

Comment: @ThomasWeller as I said at top, I expect the host ip address

Comment: @jpaugh forget the VM, I'm not using it, I just have it installed and want MY host ip, as in ipconfig -> Wi-fi adapter.

Comment: @sooaran So, all of this is happening on the physical machine? Okay.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/270745/how-do-i-determine-all-of-my-ip-addresses-when-i-have-multiple-nics

Comment: @jpaugh exactly! 
And, to add more information, my script have to retrieve the host's ip address, independently if there's  VMware, VirtualBox, etc... I mean, when I run the script in a machine named X, I have to get that physical machine's IP address

Comment: @sooaran I got it. When a VM is installed, it installs a software NIC; so I do believe Thomas Weller's duplicate link will help you. You'll need to distinguish the NICs by device ID or MAC address, and then pick the right one. Alternately, you could get all the IP addresses, and filter them by the subnet you expect it to be on.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I determine all of my IP addresses when I have multiple NICs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/270745/how-do-i-determine-all-of-my-ip-addresses-when-i-have-multiple-nics)

Comment: I edited to remove the ambiguity caused by having a problem caused by a VM on the *host OS*. I think that might be the reason for a downvote.

Comment: thanks @jpaugh , I'm already checking that question out . And probably follow your advice about filtering the ip addresses...

Answer (score -1):

if you are using Windows you can make this

```
iphost = socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname())
```