# How to get all IP addresses using Python (Windows)?

Tags: python, windows

I've been reading about the following solutions here, but it only works for one IP Address only. I'm not able to print the rest of the IPs (multiple network/wireless cards).

**References**

1. http://net-informations.com/python/net/ipadress.htm
2. [Finding local IP addresses using Python's stdlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/166506/finding-local-ip-addresses-using-pythons-stdlib?page=2&tab=votes#tab-top)
3. [How do I determine all of my IP addresses when I have multiple NICs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/270745/how-do-i-determine-all-of-my-ip-addresses-when-i-have-multiple-nics)

```
C:\>ipconfig | findstr IPv4
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.1
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.5.1

C:\>python
Python 3.5.1 (v3.5.1:37a07cee5969, Dec  6 2015, 01:38:48) [MSC v.1900 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import socket
>>> print (socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname()))
192.168.5.1
>>>
```

Please let me know how to print all IP Addresses in Python.

**Update 1:**

As suggested by Rahul, I've tried the following code but it didn't return anything on the screen.

```
c:\Python\Codes>more ip.py
from netifaces import interfaces, ifaddresses, AF_INET

def ip4_addresses():
    ip_list = []
    for interface in interfaces():
        for link in ifaddresses(interface)[AF_INET]:
            ip_list.append(link['addr'])
    return ip_list

c:\Python\Codes>

c:\Python\Codes>ip.py

c:\Python\Codes>
```

**Update 2:**

I've also tried Elemag's code as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33946251/9013730). It works on Python interpreter but not when I save the code to .py

```
c:\Python\Codes>python
Python 3.5.1 (v3.5.1:37a07cee5969, Dec  6 2015, 01:38:48) [MSC v.1900 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>
>>> [netifaces.ifaddresses(iface)[netifaces.AF_INET][0]['addr'] for iface in netifaces.interfaces() if netifaces.AF_INET in netifa
ces.ifaddresses(iface)]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'netifaces' is not defined
>>>
>>> import netifaces
>>> [netifaces.ifaddresses(iface)[netifaces.AF_INET][0]['addr'] for iface in netifaces.interfaces() if netifaces.AF_INET in netifa
ces.ifaddresses(iface)]
['192.168.1.10', '192.168.56.1', '127.0.0.1']
>>>
>>> ^Z
```

It's not working when I save the code into .py

```
c:\Python\Codes>more test.py
[netifaces.ifaddresses(iface)[netifaces.AF_INET][0]['addr'] for iface in netifaces.interfaces() if netifaces.AF_INET in netifaces.
ifaddresses(iface)]

c:\Python\Codes>test.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Python\Codes\test.py", line 1, in <module>
    [netifaces.ifaddresses(iface)[netifaces.AF_INET][0]['addr'] for iface in netifaces.interfaces() if netifaces.AF_INET in netifa
ces.ifaddresses(iface)]
NameError: name 'netifaces' is not defined

c:\Python\Codes>

c:\Python\Codes>more test.py
import netifaces
[netifaces.ifaddresses(iface)[netifaces.AF_INET][0]['addr'] for iface in netifaces.interfaces() if netifaces.AF_INET in netifaces.
ifaddresses(iface)]

c:\Python\Codes>

c:\Python\Codes>test.py

c:\Python\Codes>
```

Comment: 1. There's no concept of `returning to the screen`. 2. You don't even call function `ip_adresses()` anywhere. Your program does essentially nothing.

Comment: Thanks @ElmoVanKielmo 

I've added `print (ip4_addresses)` but not getting the output I expected.

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 3):

I used the following example from this site as a starting point (changed to work in Python 3): 
https://yamakira.github.io/python-network-programming/libraries/netifaces/index.html
as well as info from the module:
https://pypi.org/project/netifaces/

```
import netifaces
for iface in netifaces.interfaces():
  iface_details = netifaces.ifaddresses(iface)
  if netifaces.AF_INET in iface_details:
    print(iface_details[netifaces.AF_INET])
```

which returns interface info in dictionary form:

```
[{'addr': '192.168.0.90', 'netmask': '255.255.255.0', 'broadcast': '192.168.0.255'}]
[{'addr': '127.0.0.1', 'netmask': '255.0.0.0', 'broadcast': '127.255.255.255'}]
```

as an extension to this, if you do something like:

```
import netifaces
for iface in netifaces.interfaces():
    iface_details = netifaces.ifaddresses(iface)
    if netifaces.AF_INET in iface_details:
        print(iface_details[netifaces.AF_INET])
        for ip_interfaces in iface_details[netifaces.AF_INET]:
            for key, ip_add in ip_interfaces.items():
                if key == 'addr' and ip_add != '127.0.0.1':
                    print(key, ip_add)
```

This would return your IP address in my case:

```
addr 192.168.0.90
```

Obviously, you can manipulate the dictionary as you see fit, I just added it for information sake

- tested on windows 10 python 3.6
- tested on linux python 2.7, 3.6

hope this helps someone

Answer (score 0):

```
from netifaces import interfaces, ifaddresses, AF_INET
def ip4_addresses():
       ip_list = []
       for interface in interfaces():
           for link in ifaddresses(interface)[AF_INET]:
               ip_list.append(link['addr'])
       return ip_list
print(ip4_addresses())
```

Reference: [How do I determine all of my IP addresses when I have multiple NICs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/270745/how-do-i-determine-all-of-my-ip-addresses-when-i-have-multiple-nics)

Comment: Thanks @Rahul, I tried the code but nothing happen

`c:\Python\Codes>more ip.py
from netifaces import interfaces, ifaddresses, AF_INET

def ip4_addresses():
    ip_list = []
    for interface in interfaces():
        for link in ifaddresses(interface)[AF_INET]:
            ip_list.append(link['addr'])
    return ip_list


c:\Python\Codes>ip.py

c:\Python\Codes>`

Comment: use `print(ip4_addresses())` to print the output. I have updated my code, take a look at it. Thank you

Comment: Didn't work.

`print(ip4_addresses())` caused the following error.

`c:\Python\Codes>ip.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Python\Codes\ip.py", line 8, in <module>
    print(ip4_addresses())
  File "c:\Python\Codes\ip.py", line 5, in ip4_addresses
    for link in ifaddresses(interface)[AF_INET]:
KeyError: 2

c:\Python\Codes>`