# Finding an interface name from an IP address

Tags: c, linux

I need to get the interface name by providing an IP address. There is no system call to get this.

I need an implementation for this in C or C++

Already the reverse of this is available on Stack Overflow, *[Finding an IP address from an interface name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/259389/finding-an-ip-from-an-interface-name)*.

Comment: maybe a little more info might be helpful?

Answer (score 21):

Use [`getifaddrs(3)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getifaddrs.3.html). Simple example. Usage "./foo 123.45.67.89" Please add error checking etc:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <net/if.h>
#include <ifaddrs.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  struct ifaddrs *addrs, *iap;
  struct sockaddr_in *sa;
  char buf[32];

  getifaddrs(&addrs);
  for (iap = addrs; iap != NULL; iap = iap->ifa_next) {
    if (iap->ifa_addr && (iap->ifa_flags & IFF_UP) && iap->ifa_addr->sa_family == AF_INET) {
      sa = (struct sockaddr_in *)(iap->ifa_addr);
      inet_ntop(iap->ifa_addr->sa_family, (void *)&(sa->sin_addr), buf, sizeof(buf));
      if (!strcmp(argv[1], buf)) {
        printf("%s\n", iap->ifa_name);
      }
    }
  }
  freeifaddrs(addrs);
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 13):

Could you simply parse the output from something like

```
 netstat -ie | grep -B1 "192.168.21.10"
```

The -B1 part tells grep we want to include the line *before* the match in the output, so we get this:

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:13:72:79:65:23
          inet addr:192.168.21.10  Bcast:192.168.21.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
```

Once you have confidence you're getting the output you need, you can condense it further into a one-liner....

```
netstat -ie | grep -B1 "192.168.21.10" | head -n1 | awk '{print $1}'
```

which just returns "eth0"

Comment: i need to call a function from a c/c++  program

Comment: look at the source of netstat or ifconfig to see how it does it. Generally packaged with net-tools.

Answer (score 3):

Sometimes, `ip route list` might be enough to filter an interface and provide a neat output. It's not based on an "ip address" but the network it belongs to.

```
ip route list 10.9.0.0/24 | awk '{print $3}'
eno2
```

Answer (score 0):

More reliable:

```
netstat -ie | grep -B1 ":10.2.34.3 " | head -n1 | awk '{print $1}'
```

`netstat -ie | grep -B1 "<ip-address>"` must be used carefully, because if you have multiple network adapters with  e.g  `IP1= 210.2.3.4 (eth0)` and  `IP2=10.2.3.4  (eth1)`, then the  command `netstat -ie | grep -B1 "10.2.3.4"` would find both adapters as result. But the expected result is only one.

So the more reliable version is:

```
netstat -ie | grep -B1 ":<ip-address> "
```

(pay attention the blank at the end - it is intentional)