# Is lo always the first interface of ip a command

Tags: bash, interface

So I have this script which is there to change the IP of a Linux client. I had the weird bug, that my current method of getting the interface uses "lo" if "eno1" does not have an IP assigned. The current method to get the interface is

```
iface=$(ifconfig | head -1 | awk '{print $1}' | sed "s/://g")
```

So now my question. I found a new method to get the default interface, it works as following:

```
iface=$(ip a | grep "2:" | cut -d ":" -f2 | xargs)
```

I need to know if "lo" is always the interface on the position 1: when using the command `ip a`

Or if anyone knows a more generic method to get the interface, I would appreciate to hear it.

Comment: I donno if it helps, but getting interface name in `C` as mentioned in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/427517/finding-an-interface-name-from-an-ip-address) and making your own command out of it?

Comment: @Mihir thanks for the link, but I'd prefeer if I could do this without any additional utilities.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be on the safe side:

```
ip a | grep "^[0-9]:" | grep -v lo: | cut -d ":" -f2 | xargs
```

Comment: Oh, how could I forget about grep -v, thanks a lot. I think this will solve my problem.

Answer (score 1):

General comments:

```
I need to know if "lo" is always the interface on the position 1: when using the command ip a
```

In practice, yes. But never count on this unless documented.

```
Or if anyone knows a more generic method to get the interface, I would appreciate to hear it.
```

ip is the correct method to use, surely over ifconfig.