# How to get system interface name from IP

Tags: go, network-programming

Here I am trying to get Interface name from a given local IP address:

```golang
func retrieveInterfaceFromIP(myIP net.IP) (string, error) {
    ifaces, err := net.Interfaces()
    if err != nil {
        return "", err
    }
    for _, iface := range ifaces {
        addrs, err := iface.Addrs()
        if err != nil {
            return "", err
        }
        for _, addr := range addrs {
            fmt.Println(addr.String())
            ip, _, err := net.ParseCIDR(addr.String())
            if err != nil {
                return "", err
            }
            if myIP.String() == ip.String() {
                return iface.Name, nil
            }
        }
    }
    return "", fmt.Errorf("Not able to identify interface for %s", myIP)
}
```

Is there any straight function call to get the Interface name from a given IP?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not aware of any.

But I think your code should be a little modified. So, you are returning in case there's any error without taking into account that if you have already checked the correct interface from which you might get the correct result. Well, when checking multiple interfaces the error could be due to any reason and you should ingore them and let the loop continue to check all other interfaces as well.

Also during benchmarking the function I've written below is **slightly** better performing:

```
goos: darwin
goarch: amd64
BenchmarkRetrieveInterfaceFromIP-8         15768         75635 ns/op       16336 B/op        254 allocs/op
BenchmarkGetInterfaceByIP-8                16748         71968 ns/op       16192 B/op        244 allocs/op
```

> Note: `BenchmarkGetInterfaceByIP` is the benchmarking for my function and `BenchmarkRetrieveInterfaceFromIP` is the benchmarking of your function.

```
func getInterfaceByIP(ip net.IP) (string, error) {
    interfaces, err := net.Interfaces()
    if err != nil {
        return "", err
    }
    for _, iface := range interfaces {
        if addrs, err := iface.Addrs(); err == nil {
            for _, addr := range addrs {
                if iip, _, err := net.ParseCIDR(addr.String()); err == nil {
                    if iip.Equal(ip) {
                        return iface.Name, nil
                    }
                } else {
                    continue
                }
            }
        } else {
            continue
        }
    }
    return "", errors.New("couldn't find a interface for the ip")
}
```

And yes, I think that people using *C/C++* are doing similar things because from one of the answers I saw related to a similar question (for `C`), they leverage from [getifaddrs(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getifaddrs.3.html) which is similar to what we have done. [[Reference]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/429467/5821408)

Comment: thank you so much for you feedback and comment. I like it.