# How to enumerate all IP addresses attached to a machine, in POSIX C?

Tags: c, sockets, ip-address, posix

**Background:**

I'm writing a daemon that makes outgoing TCP/IP connections.  It will be running on machines with multiple (non-loopback) IP addresses.  I'd like the users to be able to specify, in the daemon's config file, which IP address(es) to use for outgoing connections, or `*` to use all.

The addresses will be used in a rotation, each connection going out from the IP address used least recently.  This behavior is important, as is `*` being a replacement for "all" so daemons running on multiple machines can point to the same config file on a fileshare, and have each use its own set of IP addresses.

**Problem:**

How do I get a list of all the IP addresses a machine can make outgoing (i.e. to any other computer) connections on?  Given a list of all IP addresses, how would I filter out loopback addresses?

I'm in C, and if possible I'd like to use POSIX only, but the daemon will probably only ever run on Linux boxes, so I'd accept a Linux-centric answer.

Each IP address will be available on exactly one (possibly virtual) network device and vice versa, so a way to enumerate network devices and get associated IP addresses would also suffice, though I wouldn't really be happy about it.  (Side questions: Is it even possible to associate multiple IP addresses with a single device? How 'bout the same IP under multiple devices? Not important.)

**Insufficient Solutions:**

- `gethostname()`/`gethostbyname()` (as [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/122208/get-the-ip-address-of-local-computer)).  Using that method, I only ever get 127.0.0.1 back (or .1.1 in Debian).  I suspect this is because the hostname of the machine is in the `hosts` file, and that's as far as `gethostbyname()` checks.  (I believe that's why in Debian I always get 127.0.1.1: Debian defaults to adding localhost as 127.0.0.1 and the machine's hostname as 127.0.1.1 to the `hosts` file, right?)  I'd like a solution that ignores `hosts` and gives me everything actually there.
- I've had no more luck with `getaddrinfo()` than `gethostname()`/`gethostbyname()`.  It seems to be bound by the same problem.  I tested this passing the machine's hostname and a `NULL` service (port) into it; the docs say passing a `NULL` hostname AND a `NULL` service is illegal, and this is backed up by testing.  Not sure how else to ask it for everything on the machine, but I'm open to suggestions in this vein.
- EDIT: [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/259389/finding-an-ip-from-an-interface-name/259424#259424) shows how to get the IP address from a device name, but doesn't show how to enumerate the device names.  Any ideas?

FINAL EDIT: I've accepted [caskey's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1160963/how-to-enumerate-all-ip-addresses-attached-to-a-machine-in-posix-c/1161018#1161018) to give him the credit for pointing me in the direction of how this needs to be done.  I've posted my [own answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1160963/how-to-enumerate-all-ip-addresses-attached-to-a-machine-in-posix-c/1162010#1162010) listing the source code of how exactly to do it in case anyone else needs it.

Comment: I meant `man netdevice` but then I realized it wasn't POSIX, so it's moot.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This can only be done in an operating system dependent fashion.  You could try parsing the output of 'iptables', but the *right* answer for linux is to use ioctl.

> ```
> SIOCGIFCONF  takes  a  struct  ifconf *.  The ifc_buf field points to a
>       buffer of length ifc_len bytes, into which the kernel writes a list of
>       type struct ifreq [].
> ```

The struct ifreq is documented in linux/if.h:

```
struct ifreq 
{
#define IFHWADDRLEN     6
        union
        {
                char    ifrn_name[IFNAMSIZ];            /* if name, e.g. "en0" */
        } ifr_ifrn;

        union {
                struct  sockaddr ifru_addr;
                struct  sockaddr ifru_dstaddr;
                struct  sockaddr ifru_broadaddr;
                struct  sockaddr ifru_netmask;
                struct  sockaddr ifru_hwaddr;
                short   ifru_flags;
                int     ifru_ivalue;
                int     ifru_mtu;
                struct  ifmap ifru_map;
                char    ifru_slave[IFNAMSIZ];   /* Just fits the size */
                char    ifru_newname[IFNAMSIZ];
                void *  ifru_data;
                struct  if_settings ifru_settings;
        } ifr_ifru;
};
```

As you can see, it contains the address information you desire.

Answer (score 9):

Here's my proof of concept code using [caskey's accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1160963/how-to-enumerate-all-ip-addresses-attached-to-a-machine-in-posix-c/1161018#1161018), for posterity's sake:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/ioctl.h>
#include <net/if.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>


static const char * flags(int sd, const char * name)
{
    static char buf[1024];

    static struct ifreq ifreq;
    strcpy(ifreq.ifr_name, name);

    int r = ioctl(sd, SIOCGIFFLAGS, (char *)&ifreq);
    assert(r == 0);

    int l = 0;
#define FLAG(b) if(ifreq.ifr_flags & b) l += snprintf(buf + l, sizeof(buf) - l, #b " ")
    FLAG(IFF_UP);
    FLAG(IFF_BROADCAST);
    FLAG(IFF_DEBUG);
    FLAG(IFF_LOOPBACK);
    FLAG(IFF_POINTOPOINT);
    FLAG(IFF_RUNNING);
    FLAG(IFF_NOARP);
    FLAG(IFF_PROMISC);
    FLAG(IFF_NOTRAILERS);
    FLAG(IFF_ALLMULTI);
    FLAG(IFF_MASTER);
    FLAG(IFF_SLAVE);
    FLAG(IFF_MULTICAST);
    FLAG(IFF_PORTSEL);
    FLAG(IFF_AUTOMEDIA);
    FLAG(IFF_DYNAMIC);
#undef FLAG

    return buf;
}

int main(void)
{
    static struct ifreq ifreqs[32];
    struct ifconf ifconf;
    memset(&ifconf, 0, sizeof(ifconf));
    ifconf.ifc_req = ifreqs;
    ifconf.ifc_len = sizeof(ifreqs);

    int sd = socket(PF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    assert(sd >= 0);

    int r = ioctl(sd, SIOCGIFCONF, (char *)&ifconf);
    assert(r == 0);

    for(int i = 0; i < ifconf.ifc_len/sizeof(struct ifreq); ++i)
    {
        printf("%s: %s\n", ifreqs[i].ifr_name, inet_ntoa(((struct sockaddr_in *)&ifreqs[i].ifr_addr)->sin_addr));
        printf(" flags: %s\n", flags(sd, ifreqs[i].ifr_name));
    }

    close(sd);

    return 0;
}
```

Works like a charm!

Comment: This isn't applicable for your particular problem, but one note that might be useful for anyone who is looking at this code is that SIOCGICONF will only report interfaces that have an assigned address. If you are looking for all _interfaces_ instead of all _addresses_, you must (on Linux) parse /proc/net/dev.

Answer (score 1):

Some answers to side questions:

- Adding multiple IPs to a device can be done with aliasing. Linux creates devices named like eth0:0 when you do this.

  `ifconfig eth0:0 10.0.0.1`
- Having the same IP under multiple devices can be done with channel bonding/link aggregation.

Comment: Word.  I was aware of virtual devices (which is what I've always heard devices like eth0:1 called)--is it possible to have multiple IPs per logical device, as in, without separating the device into aliases?

Comment: Not that I can figure out, at least on Linux.

On FreeBSD, however, no suffix is created, leading to devices that can look like:
    bge0: flags=8843<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> metric 0 mtu 1500
        options=9b<RXCSUM,TXCSUM,VLAN_MTU,VLAN_HWTAGGING,VLAN_HWCSUM>
        ether 00:11:22:33:44:55
        inet 10.0.0.2 netmask 0xffffff00 broadcast 10.0.0.255
        inet 10.0.0.3 netmask 0xffffff00 broadcast 10.0.0.255
        ...
These are still referred to as aliases, mind you.

Comment: It's not possible with Linux's `ifconfig`, but Linux's `ip` command can do it.  For example, `ip addr add dev lo 127.0.0.2/8` will give a second address to `lo`, which works even though `ifconfig` can't deal with it.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the interface info required a couple of ways including calling ioctl() with the SIOCGIFCONF option and looping through the returned structures to get the interface address info.

> Given a list of all IP addresses, how would I filter out loopback addresses?

See ifreq struct in caskey's answer.  You can determine the loopback (properly) with:

```
if (ifru_flags & IFF_LOOPBACK)
```

Constants are in if.h

Answer (score 0):

**How do I get a list of all the IP addresses a machine can make outgoing (i.e. to any other computer) connections on? Given a list of all IP addresses, how would I filter out loopback addresses?**

Look at the source code of **lsof** and **netstat**. You'll see it involves traversing kernel memory structures, not just making system calls.

Answer (score -1):

are you sure you are using gethostname()/gethostbyname() correctly? check out [here](http://windows-programming.suite101.com/article.cfm/socket_programming_gethostbyname), the only problem I see with doing this is that it's possible that a domain name has multiple ip addresses mapped to it. If that's the case then there's no way of knowing what the ip address belonging to the local machine is