# Detect if IP is static or obtained from DHCP on busybox

Tags: c, embedded, dhcp

I am working on embedded device who run BusyBox.
The system is getting its address by using the ip command.
I want to figure out from my C program whether the device 
ip static or received from DHCP server. How do I do that?

Comment: I think you should edit your question with details on how you get the IP address in the first place. I assumed you ran BusyBox' dhcp client, but that seems wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you control the enviroment, I suggest setting an env variable, or creating a flag file somewhere you can stat, when the IP adress is set.

Answer (score 4):

I don't know how your users interact with your embedded system. But on ours (same components) we have CLI that registers the chosen DHCP/STATIC type setting in a SHM struct (db) per interface.

Essentially, you need to keep track of how the IP of an interface was set.

Answer (score 1):

The [dumpleases](http://www.busybox.net/downloads/BusyBox.html#dumpleases) command is supposed to show the current leases. I guess if you can determine that you have an IP address, but no lease, then the address is static.

Comment: the device get its address using ip command and not udhcp so dumpleases does not work

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1160963/how-to-enumerate-all-ip-addresses-attached-to-a-machine-in-posix-c) and check the IFF_DYNAMIC flag - that may be set when DHCP is active on an interface.

Comment: IFF_DYNAMIC indicate dialup device with changing addresses

Comment: in Solaris there is IFF_DHCPRUNNING flag. Is there Linux equivalent ?