# How I Can Print The IP Of The Host

Tags: c++, printing, localhost, ip

I'm learning C++ and i want to know how i can print the IP adress of the host machine, but remember that my program is a command line aplication(*cmd*), but i don't want the code, but some links here i can learn this, not copy and paste. Thanks!

Comment: BTW, don't forget a single host may have several IP addresses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this out: [Socket Programming](http://windows-programming.suite101.com/article.cfm/socket_programming_gethostbyname).

Winsock looks like a good choice.

Answer (score 1):

Google = [How to find local ip addresses c++](http://www.codeguru.com/forum/showthread.php?t=233261)

Answer (score 1):

It's a very good approach to ask for something to learn, not ready code.

Read this if you are on Linux: [Get the IP address of the machine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/212528/linux-c-get-the-ip-address-of-local-computer)

...or this if you are on Windows: http://www.codeguru.com/forum/showthread.php?t=233261

You could have found this on your own with a simple Google search.

// Edit: DeusAduro's link for Windows was much better. Changed it.