# How to get the current ip address in C++

Tags: c++

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [get global ip address](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3220821/get-global-ip-address)

I am wondering is there anyway to get the ipv4 address easily?

Comment: which platform? Windows/Linux/Max??

Comment: @user705414: What platform are you using? Linux/Unix/Windows?

Comment: Every computer has an IPv4 address of 127.0.0.1. Can you use that?

Comment: Each network adapter (physical and virtual) can have multiple IP addresses, so you need to specify your requirement better. It also depends on the OS you use.

Comment: prefer platform independent. But it is windows

Answer (score 2):

For the local computer:

[Get the IP address of the machine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/212528/linux-c-get-the-ip-address-of-local-computer)

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the OS your program running on.

For Windows see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365915%28v=VS.85%29.aspx

Comment: If you want the regular IPv4 address, you should access the unicast address value.

Answer (score 0):

Try **Beej's Guide to Network Programming** at http://beej.us/guide/bgnet/

There you may find an answer for your platform and the case of multiple addresses.

Answer (score 0):

Actually C++ standard library does not provide any function to get the ip address of a system. The api for that must be provided by the OS on which you are working.

From your question what I understood is you are working on something but your IP keep changing because it is assigned by DHCP, well I may be wrong.

However, for linux you would like to google for inet_ntop

Check this out:
`#include <arpa/inet.h>

const char *inet_ntop(int af, const void *src,
                      char *dst, socklen_t size);`