# glib get ip address from route

Tags: c, ip, glib

How can I get ip address with C/glib of my local computer which get from route.

Comment: possibly a duplication of [Linux / C++: Get the IP Address of local computer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/265978/640650)? It's not a glib solution but a C one.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really sure what you mean with "get from route".

But if want to get the IP you're using outside your LAN then just wrap up this command into a system call.

```
curl -s http://myip.dk/ | egrep -m1 -o '[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}'
```

It always works.

Answer (score 0):

You can use libgtop, in particular you can use a mix of [netlist](http://developer.gnome.org/libgtop/stable/libgtop-Net-List.html) and [netload](http://developer.gnome.org/libgtop/stable/libgtop-Net-Load.html).  With netlist you can get the network interface list, and with netload you can get the information for each interface (or the interface you are interested in).