# Can I get the names of all the domains a Linux computer is connected to in C++?

Tags: c++, linux, dns

I have a Linux machine that is connected (by external NICs) to 2 external domains. I want to get the names of the domains my machine is connected to programmatically using C++. How can I get all these names in my application?

By the way, I have already tried `getnameinfo`, and it doesn't work for me. So please suggest another answer.

Also, it would be more helpful to me if your answers included sample code.

Comment: Uh...what?  I don't get this question at all.

Comment: Maybe Kerberos realms, therefore `klist` equivalent in the Kerberos API http://www.h5l.org/manual/heimdal-1-3-branch/krb5/

Comment: What kind of domains are you talking about here? Windows Active Directory domains?

Comment: Cde Gray - Windows Active Directory domains. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Here is similar topic  [Linux / C++: Get the IP Address of local computer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/212528/linux-c-get-the-ip-address-of-local-computer)