# C++ LINUX get all machine connected domain names

Tags: c++, linux, dns

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can I get the names of all the domains a Linux computer is connected to in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4704612/can-i-get-the-names-of-all-the-domains-a-linux-computer-is-connected-to-in-c)

Hi

My Linux machine is connected (by external NICs) to 2 external domains.
I want to discover in my linux c++ application all the names of domains my machine is connected to.
how can I get all these names?

BTW: if getnameinfo can do it - it doesn't work for me. please suggest another answer.

PLEASE ATTACH CODE EXAMPLE

10x!

Comment: Machines aren't connected to domain names. Not sure exactly what you're after. Maybe just grab all local IPs, and resolve each?

Comment: derobert - how can I resolve each IP to domain name - that's my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get a list of domains the DNS resolver is going to search from `/etc/resolv.conf`

```
$ cat /etc/resolv.conf 
# Generated by NetworkManager
search anon.local int.anon.co.uk
nameserver 10.201.13.10
nameserver 10.213.13.10
nameserver 8.8.8.8
```

In the above there is `search` directive with a list of domains to search. So, when you try to resolve hostname X, it is going to search for X, X.anon.local and X.int.anon.co.uk.