# c++ linux - getting the interface from IP

Tags: c++, linux, networking

in C++ linux application, how can I get the network interface reffering to each IP on my machine?
IP contains: static IP and dynamic IP

Note: I can't use the system call getnameinfo

10x

Comment: Prob this question can help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/212528/linux-c-get-the-ip-address-of-local-computer

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [getifaddrs](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man3/getifaddrs.3.html) call; however, note that this only retrieves one address per interface. If that's not sufficient, use the [rtnetlink](http://linux.die.net/man/7/rtnetlink) protocol over a netlink socket; [libnetlink](http://swoolley.org/man.cgi/3/libnetlink) may make this easier.

Comment: `getifaddrs()` is implemented (on Linux) using netlink.  It's the right interface (and it can return multiple addresses per interface - they just appear in multiple `struct ifaddrs`).

Answer (score 2):

It's quite tricky to do this, I believe you need to have root access. You need to issue an `ioctl` (something like `SIOCGIFCONF`) which then returns you a list of all interfaces, and then you can issue further `ioctl` calls to extract status information, etc.

Comment: Neither is root needed, nor is SIOCGIFCONF a timely interface. Avoid.

Comment: stracing `ip addr` shows it using netlink sockets; and, of course, `/bin/ip` is not setuid :)

Comment: @user562374, I did say "I believe", not "it requires", the last time I did this was almost four years ago (but that was for capturing packets off of the interfaces - which did require root - hence the misconception), also, it is a valid mechanism for querying all interfaces on a box, it's not deprecated(?) so what's wrong with it?

Comment: SIGCGIFCONF won't return ipv6 addresses - and with the IANA pool depleted this is going to be a very important concern soon

Comment: @bdonlan, very true, definitely netlink if you've got ipv6 in your setup (but I'd hazard that most likely the OP's is on a private network, which is ipv4...) I've yet to encounter a private network that is using ipv6 though...