# Filter UDP packets from a particular IP

Tags: c++, sockets, udp, ip-address

I have a program which transmits(broadcasts) and receives UDP packets simultaneously using pthreads. What I want to do is to remove packets which have been sent by me. How do I do that? My receive code currently looks as follows:

```
void *receive_thread_body(void *arg)
{
  long msg = 0;

  while(msg<500)
  {
    fd_set socket_set;
    FD_ZERO(&socket_set);
    FD_SET(b_sock,&socket_set);
    struct timeval tm;
    tm.tv_usec = 10;
    tm.tv_sec = 0;

    int ret = select(b_sock+1,&socket_set,0,0,&tm);

    if(ret == -1)
    {
      std::cout<<"select failed";
    }

    if(FD_ISSET(b_sock,&socket_set) != 0)
    {
      int recvStringLen = recvfrom(b_sock, &msg, sizeof(msg), 0, NULL, 0);
      if(recvStringLen < 0)
      {
        std::cout<<"recvfrom failed";
      }
      else
      {
        printf("\t\t\tRX: %d\n",msg);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: you want to discard packets you've sent to yourself? why are you sending them in the first place? (sorry if I completely misunderstood you)

Comment: Actually, there are multiple transceivers and hence I am not interested in receiving the packages sent by me but sent by others. Hence, I wish to discard those sent by me.

Comment: I still don't understand you setup, but: how do you distinguish a packet coming from "yourself" from one coming from "someone else"?

Comment: I should be able to distinguish the packets from the sender IP, but I dont have access to it as of moment. The answer which has just turned up looks to be correct. Will have to check it out.

Comment: @Mat - if you have several computers broadcasting stuff and you only want the broadcasts from others - that would be a reasonable scenario. Depends on the protocol I would put some ID inside the UDP message itself, but if that's not possible - then filtering by the sender is indeed the only option.

Comment: well it does start to make sens if there are multiple IPs involved. The only thing mentioned in the question is multiple threads - was having a hard time wrapping my head around an app sending itself packets and having to discard them :-)

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention that I am broadcasting the packets!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to fill the last two parameters of the `recvfrom` call - that will be the sender's address.

Then compare it to the list of your own addresses for matches (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/212528/linux-c-get-the-ip-address-of-local-computer) for example for relevant info).

This method is agnostic to the way of sending - you can use it on connection or connection-less sockets, and of course on broadcast or multicast (or unicast) transmissions.

Comment: If you have access to the local socket that you are using for sending, you can simply use `getsockname()` on that socket to find the local address to compare with.

Answer (score 2):

If you are talking about Multicast, unset the IP(V6)?_MULTICAST_LOOP option (which may be enabled by default) to not receive what you send. Note that this will prevent other applications on the same host to receive what you sent.

```
int zero = 0;
err = setsockopt(fd, IPPROTO_IPV6, IPV6_MULTICAST_LOOP, &zero, sizeof zero);
```

I haven't heard of an equivalent for broadcast. But broadcast is so old that it was replaced by Multicast in the IPv6 standard.