# Any C (Unix/Linux) equivalent for Java socket.getLocalAddress().getHostAddress()

Tags: java, c, sockets, unix

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Linux / C++: Get the IP Address of local computer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/212528/linux-c-get-the-ip-address-of-local-computer)

I'm porting a software made in java with the and the local address for the socket is needed.
I'm looking for a equivalent for the lines:

```
    Socket socket;
    ...
    InetAddress internal = socket.getLocalAddress();
    String localIp = internal.getHostAddress();
```

Comment: I guess my question is a has a dup.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The functions you are looking for are [`getsockname`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/getsockname) and [`inet_ntop`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/inet_ntop).

Comment: `code`    struct sockaddr_in addr;
    size_t addr_len = sizeof(addr);

    if (getsockname(socketfd, (struct sockaddr *) &addr, (socklen_t *) &addr_len) < 0) {
        ERROR_PRINT("Error getting local address");
        return NULL;
    }
    return inet_ntoa(addr.sin_addr);`code`

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps [getpeername](http://linux.die.net/man/2/getpeername) or [getsockname](http://linux.die.net/man/2/getsockname) ?

Comment: As a sidenote, `getpeername` gets the address of the _peer_, i.e. the remote end-point. `getsockname` gets the address of the local end-point.