# How to get IP address use ndk in android(not localhost)?

Tags: android, c, sockets, android-ndk

The code I used show below:

```
ANSICHAR HostName[256];
gethostname(HostName,256);

struct addrinfo *AddrInfo = NULL;
getaddrinfo(HostName, NULL, NULL, &AddrInfo);

for (struct addrinfo *i = AddrInfo; i != NULL; i = i->ai_next)
{
    if (i->ai_family == AF_INET)
    {
        const in_addr &IP = ((sockaddr_in *) i->ai_addr)->sin_addr;
        if (IP.s_addr != 0)
        {
            Addr.SetIp(IP);
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is "HostName" got by "gethostname(HostName,256)" is "localhost".
So the final IP I get is "127.0.0.1".
It diffent between the IP address I get used "adb shell ifconfig wlan0".

How can I get the correct IP address?

Comment: This is a duplicate question. Android NDK allows you to use the same methods as on Linux: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/212528/linux-c-get-the-ip-address-of-local-computer

Comment: @BitBank Are you sure this is a duplicate? I just tried to compile using `getifaddrs()` with the Android NDK r8d and I get the error `undefined reference to 'getifaddrs'`. Perhaps it is not implemented in Android.

Comment: You may be right. For my app, I get the local IP address in Java:
  WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager) getSystemService(WIFI_SERVICE);
  WifiInfo wifiInfo = wifiManager.getConnectionInfo();
  int ipAddress = wifiInfo.getIpAddress();

Comment: Indeed, getifaddrs is not available until API 24, IIRC. Most devices cannot use that function.