# How to get local IP address and port in Unix socket programming?

Tags: c, sockets, unix, ip, port

I used this as the address to create a new server(`socket()`, `bind()`, `listen()`):

```
struct sockaddr_in newServer;
memset(&newServer, 0, sizeof(newServer));
newServer.sin_family = AF_INET;
newServer.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);
newServer.sin_port = htons(UNUSED_PORT);
```

The macro UNUSED_PORT is defined as 0.

I expect to get a server listening on any interface and on an unused port.

I tried to use `getsockname()` to get my local IP address and port, but I got some strange outputs. The output code as below:

```
struct sockaddr_in localAddress;
socklen_t addressLength;
getsockname(newServerfd, (struct sockaddr*)&localAddress,   \
                &addressLength);
printf("local address: %s\n", inet_ntoa( localAddress.sin_addr));
printf("local port: %d\n", (int) ntohs(localAddress.sin_port));
```

For example, I got 0.255.255.255:0, 0.0.0.0:0, 255.127.0.0:36237, etc.
and my system is Mac OS X 10.7.3.

--update--

After using `socklen_t addressLength = sizeof(localAddress);` (thanks to @cnicutar and @Jonathan Leffler), I always get 0.0.0.0 for local IP; is that all right?

Comment: Did you actually read [http://beej.us/guide/bgnet/](http://beej.us/guide/bgnet/)?

Comment: The above one is Beej's Guide to Network Programming

Comment: @macs seems everyone in stack overflow recommends this guide, really so good?

Comment: I think so, because it's describing all these structures in detail and step by step.

Comment: @Sebastian: It is a good guide, but it does not describe `getsockname()`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to initialize `addressLength` before calling `getsockname`:

```
socklen_t addressLength = sizeof(localAddress);
```

Comment: i always get 0.0.0.0 for local ip this time, is that normal?

Comment: If you've bound to 0.0.0.0, then yes.

Comment: @macs then how can i get the **real** ip?

Comment: @can. Take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/212528/linux-c-get-the-ip-address-of-local-computer) SO question if you want to have the IP-address(es) of your machine. What you've done so far is that you've bound a socket and this socket listens on 0.0.0.0 which means everyone can connect.

Comment: @macs thanks.i've seen that question before. and i finally get a thorough understanding of _local address_. 0.0.0.0 means every _interface_ of server accepts incoming connections, i can only get the  exact local ip from a socket that transfers data, not the listening socket, in my example.