# Determine which of the addrinfo structures returned by getaddrinfo belongs to the current machine

Tags: linux, sockets, networking, getaddrinfo

I call `getaddrinfo`. It returns a list of matching addresses. One of them belongs to the machine from which the call was made. How do I determine which one it is?

If there is no way to do so, is there anything else I can do to reliably and portably determine the IP address of a particular network interface on the current machine?

If there is no portable way, what is the Linux-specific way?

Comment: A similar question is at http://stackoverflow.com/q/212528/199122

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a function that allows one to enumerate all the network interfaces and get information about them, including IP address. The function is [getifaddrs](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man3/getifaddrs.3.html), however note that it does not seem to be portable. Anyway, this solves my problem for now.