# MPI_Init must be called by one thread only

Tags: c, mpi, cluster-computing, distributed-computing, mpich

The [ref](http://www.mpich.org/static/docs/v3.1/www3/MPI_Init.html) of MPI_Init, states:

> This routine must be called by one thread only. That thread is called the main thread and must be the thread that calls MPI_Finalize.

How to do this? I mean every example I have seen looks like [this](https://www.dartmouth.edu/~rc/classes/intro_mpi/hello_world_ex.html) and in my code, I tried:

```
MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &mpirank);
bool mpiroot = (mpirank == 0);
if(mpiroot)
  MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
```

but I got:

```
Attempting to use an MPI routine before initializing MPICH
```

However, notice that this will work fine, if I leave it as in the example, I just had to re-check, because of my code's failure [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31833360/mpi-code-does-not-work-with-2-nodes-but-with-1).

---

I am thinking that because we call `mpiexec -n 4 ./test`, 4 processes will be spawned, thus all of them will call `MPI_Init`. I just printed stuff at the very first line of `main()` and they will be printed as many times as the number of processes.

Comment: _Thread_, not process.  Every process/rank must call `MPI_Init()`.  The issue is that if you're using hybrid threading+MPI, only one thread (in *each* rank/process) can call MPI_Init; e.g., it would be in an `#pragma omp single` construct or similar.

Comment: I see @JonathanDursi, thanks, now I am going to struggle for another day in my other question..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`MPI_Init` must be the first MPI function called by your MPI program. It must be called by each process. Note that a process is not the same as a thread! If you go on to spawn threads from a process, those threads must not call `MPI_Init` again.

So your program should be something like this:

```
 int main(int argc, char **argv) 
 {
     MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
     int mpirank;
     MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &mpirank);
     // No more calls to MPI_Init in here
     ...
     MPI_Finalize();
 }
```

Comment: Thanks mort, now I can focus again on my other question, which bothers me for so many days!