# Getting the ip address of my machine in dotted decimal with C?

Tags: c, linux, ip-address

I'm trying to get a string with the ip address in dotted decimal of my machine. What I do is trying to get the string from `INADDR_LOOPBACK` with the following code.

```
char addr[INET_ADDRSTRLEN];
struct in_addr *in_addr1 = malloc(sizeof(struct in_addr));
in_addr1->s_addr = INADDR_LOOPBACK;
inet_ntop(AF_INET, in_addr1, addr, INET_ADDRSTRLEN);
printf("addr: %s\n", addr);
```

Here's what I get from the `printf`:

> 1.0.0.127

1. Why is it the localhost address reverse? Should it print
   `127.0.0.1`?
2. Honestly I was expecting to get the ip I would get calling for
   example `$ ifconfig`... not the localhost! Did I misunderstand what `INADDR_LOOBACK` does?

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but why do you allocate the `in_addr` structure dynamically? Why not define it as e.g. `struct in_addr in_addr1;`? And then use the address-of operator `&` when passing to `inet_ntop`?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude for no special reason... I'm just used to do in this way. Would defining it as you say be an improvement in performance / something else?

Comment: As for your problem, remember that the address is supposed to be in *network byte order*. See e.g. [this `inet_ntop` manual page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/inet_ntop.3.html).

Comment: Well not using pointer and dynamic allocation will mean less risk of dereferencing null or invalid pointers, or having memory leaks.

Comment: Quite probably a dupe of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/212528/get-the-ip-address-of-the-machine

Comment: Get unused to doing it that way. Allocating memory dynamically when a simple local variable will suffice is a terrible practice that would never survive a competent code review.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`INADDR_LOOPBACK` is in **host byte order**, i.e. `0x7f000001`. It is, incidentally, the IPv4 address `127.0.0.1`.

`in_addr1->s_addr` must be in **network byte order**.

Your computer is a little-endian computer where the host byte order doesn't match the network byte order. You must use `htonl` to convert the loopback address to network byte order.