# How to enumerate all available network interfaces?

Tags: c++, winapi, networking, interface, enumeration

How to enumerate all network interfaces currently available on the computer (including virtual, non-connected, loopback etc)?

I need to know their IP4/6, Mask, Gateway, DNS, WINS etc

---

*Language:* C++, WinAPI

*System:* Windows 2000 and higher (including Win7)

Comment: Consider this question:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3069082/porting-getifaddrs-to-win-xp

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Have a look at http://www.codeproject.com/KB/IP/netcfg.aspx. It's a giant example of what you want to do.

Comment: @bmarguliesm, you're the real guru of networking! Thank you a lot.

Comment: I realize this is a _really_ old answer, but is there any chance you could edit it to match with SO's new quality standards? (i.e. not link-only)

Comment: I do not have access to windows. Feel free to do it.

Answer (score 10):

It sounds like you want a combination of a few different functions.

To get a list of adapters with their IPv4 addresses/masks, associated WINS servers and DNS servers, you can use `GetAdaptersInfo`. To get IPv6 addresses, you can use `GetAdaptersAddresses`.

Depending on what is included in your "etc." you might also want `GetIfTable` and `GetIfEntry`. `GetIfTable` gets a list of network adapters. `GetIfEntry` gets you information about each. These retrieve things like the amount of data that's been transmitted/retrieved over a particular interface. There's also a `GetIfTable2`/`GetIfEntry2` that are only for Vista and newer that get more information.

If memory serves, `GetIfTable`/`GetIfEntry` list *all* the interfaces in the machine. `GetAdaptersInfo` only works with the "real" adapters.

Comment: +1 Thanks, Jerry. I'll extend the solution of @bmargulies with your recommendations

Answer (score 6):

Perversely you can use `getaddrinfo ("..localmachine")` to enumerate interfaces on Windows 2003+.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms738520(v=vs.85).aspx

Windows 7 with Service Pack 1 (SP1) and Windows Server 2008 R2 with Service Pack 1 (SP1) add support to hide interfaces.

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2386184

Comment: This has no upvotes yet? The most elegant solution of all! Thanks!