# Alternative to gethostbyname

Tags: c++, windows, gethostbyname

I can't use `gethostbyname` to grab a host's IP address, it is a deprecated function that only works 10% of the fricken' time on Windows!

I can't find any adequate resources on other ways to find a host's IP address using other functions (MSDN recommended `getaddrinfo` but that doesn't seem like what I want.)

Comment: It might improve your chances of getting a useful answer if you explained why you think getaddrinfo isn't what you want.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Actually, `getaddrinfo` is what you want.  It's just a long-winded way to do it, not to mention the fact that sometimes multiple IP addresses are found (e.g. one IPv4 address **and** one IPv6 address).  I'd recommend looking at [Beej's Guide to Network Programming](https://beej.us/guide/bgnet/), specifically [`getaddrinfo`](https://beej.us/guide/bgnet/html/#getaddrinfoprepare-to-launch).

Answer (score 10):

You can try things like [`WSAConnectByName`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms741557%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), but [`getaddrinfo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa915647.aspx) actually *is* what you want, here's [simple example](http://www.geekpage.jp/en/programming/winsock/getaddrinfo-0.php).

Answer (score 1):

You can use `gethostbyname2` which supports both IPV4 and IPV6 resolving.

This is an [article](http://www.pixelstech.net/article/1345057573-gethostbyname-vs-getaddrinfo) that shows the difference between `gethostbyname` and `getaddrinfo`, it also discusses `gethostbyname2`.