# Send http URL through C code using visual studios in Windows

Tags: c, sockets, http, visual-studio-2010

I have a video encoder which can start/stop recording by sending a URL.

Start recording: http://192.168.1.5/blah-blah/record/record.cgi

Stop recording: http://192.168.1.5/blah-blah/record/stop.cgi

I don't have to worry about getting a response. I just have to send it.

I was exploring the GET method and also trying to use [HappyHTTP](http://scumways.com/happyhttp/happyhttp.html) library.
Is there a simple way to do it without using any library?

I am using visual studios on Windows.

Comment: do you know the exact host and port of the server serving that url?

Comment: Yes, I do @Chase

Comment: Using HTTP over a plain vanilla TCP socket will work, but it requires a lot of manual work to setup. Microsoft has already done the hard work for you, wrapping the HTTP protocol with the [WinInet](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/wininet/portal) and [WinHTTP](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winhttp/about-winhttp) APIs, which are both built-in to Windows itself.

Answer (score 1):

You can use TCP connection to the server, after connected, you can send the plain HTTP request.
The following program shows this, connecting to google with TCP protocol, sending HTTP get request, and getting the first 2K of the response.

**Note:** See @Chase great comments below, the program is not complete: usage of `gethostbyname` should be avoided, as this method is deprecated, error handling should be changed to use `WSAGetLastError` and not errno, the program should call `WSACleanup` before it ends.

I don't have time now to fix the program, and I leave it as it, as someone may benefit from it as it is now.

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <Windows.h>
#include <winsock.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#pragma comment(lib, "Ws2_32.lib")

#define SERVER_PORT ((u_short )80)
#define SERVER_HOST "www.google.com"

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    int ret;
    SOCKET sd;
    struct hostent* he = { 0 };
    struct sockaddr_in addr_info = { 0 };
        
    WSADATA wsaData = { 0 };
    WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), &wsaData);

    he = gethostbyname(SERVER_HOST);
    if (he == NULL)
    {
        printf("failed to get host information for '%s': %s\n", SERVER_HOST, strerror(errno));
        exit(-1);
    }

    sd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);
    if (sd == INVALID_SOCKET)
    {
        printf("failed to create socket: %s\n", strerror(errno));
        exit(-1);
    }
    
    addr_info.sin_family = AF_INET;      
    addr_info.sin_port = htons(SERVER_PORT);    
    addr_info.sin_addr = *((struct in_addr*)he->h_addr);
    memset(&(addr_info.sin_zero), 0, sizeof(addr_info.sin_zero));     

    printf("connecting to %s ....\n", SERVER_HOST );
    ret = connect(sd, (struct sockaddr*)&addr_info, sizeof(struct sockaddr));
    if ( ret == -1)
    {
        printf("failed to connect: %s\n", strerror(errno));
        exit(-1);
    }

    printf("sending GET /index.html request ....\n");
    char send_buffer[] = "GET /index.html HTTP/1.1\r\nHost : " SERVER_HOST "\r\n\r\n";
    ret = send(sd, send_buffer, sizeof(send_buffer), 0);
    if ( ret == -1)
    {
        printf("failed to send request: %s\n", strerror(errno));
        exit(-1);
    }

    printf("getting response (first 2K)\n");
    char response_buffer[2048] = "";
    //using sizeof(response_buffer)-1 to have the buffer terminate with zero, even if it is fully consumed by the recv call. this is because I want to print it later on.
    ret = recv(sd, response_buffer, sizeof(response_buffer)-1, 0);
    if (ret == -1)
    {
        printf("failed to get response: %s\n", strerror(errno));
        exit(-1);
    }

    printf("received (first 2KB): %s\n", response_buffer);

    closesocket(sd);

    return 0;
}
```

program output is:

```
connecting to www.google.com ....
sending GET /index.html request ....
getting response (first 2K)
received: HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Tue, 29 Dec 2020 08:56:34 GMT
Expires: -1
Cache-Control: private, max-age=0
Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1
P3P: CP="This is not a P3P policy! See g.co/p3phelp for more info."
Server: gws
X-XSS-Protection: 0
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
Set-Cookie: 1P_JAR=2020-12-29-08; expires=Thu, 28-Jan-2021 08:56:34 GMT; path=/; domain=.google.com; Secure
Set-Cookie: NID=205=a7W2c7M39ojimAWRRgn7nwedmdouUrZfo8uBa1wJeEwo8DUk7ibclM-xwp5ozhKO2BYmcRnQ1l4wwjb_DYfOVsDoi-UdtqBmgySL_KlcG6zMjembghO8OL81e2iHee0_cnlDZvSCCGvPnaC0LHNzFtqeWaYSELF7-1t5Khuv4Yc; expires=Wed, 30-Jun-2021 08:56:34 GMT; path=/; domain=.google.com; HttpOnly
Accept-Ranges: none
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Transfer-Encoding: chunked

...
```

Comment: Please don't recommend use of `gethostbyname` and manual struct filling, they don't support ipv6 and [have been deprecated for a while](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6638580/alternative-to-gethostbyname) :)

Comment: Also, ["Error codes set by Windows Sockets are not made available through the `errno` variable"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winsock/error-codes-errno-h-errno-and-wsagetlasterror-2), use `WSAGetLastError` instead.

Comment: Yep, you are right on both comments. However, I don't have time now to fix the answer with your great comments. I'll leave it for a while (maybe it would be helpful to someone), then delete it

Comment: Hi @Chase, at second thought, I decided to leave the answer as it is and add your comments to the answer. I don't have time now to fix it, but it might be beneficial to someone as it is.

Comment: Thank you both for answers. I'll check and let you guys know :)

Answer (score 1):

The barebones way of sending a request to server is """*pretty simple*""".

Firstly, I'll be assuming you know the exact host and port of the url. I assume this since I cannot access the link you've provided. In most cases, you know the host being the domain you type in the url and the port being 80 for http, or 443 for https - I cannot confirm this for the given link however.

In any case, first things first - the headers you'd require on windows for socket programming is-

```c
#include <WinSock2.h>
#include <WS2tcpip.h>
```

You'll also need to link the winsock2 library, you can do this by putting `#pragma comment(lib, "Ws2_32.lib")` after your headers. Or you can put `Ws2_32.lib` in `Project Configuration -> Linker -> Input -> Additional Dependencies` in Visual Studio.

Now, winsock2 requires you to initiate the library (and also to close it). You can do this in your `main` function ideally, since the startup is required for any socket connection to be made-

```c
 /* Initialize wsock2 2.2 */
WSADATA wsadat;
if (WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), &wsadat) != 0)
{
    printf("WSAStartup failed with error %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
    return 1;
}
```

And after everything is done-

```c
/* Cleanup wsock2 */
if (WSACleanup() == SOCKET_ERROR)
{
    printf("WSACleanup failed with error %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
    return 1;
}
```

Now you need to obtain information about the server you want to connect to, we do that using [`getaddrinfo`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/ws2tcpip/nf-ws2tcpip-getaddrinfo). ([Relevant posix docs](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getaddrinfo.3.html))

```c
static struct addrinfo const hints = { .ai_family = AF_UNSPEC, .ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM };

struct addrinfo* addrs;
int gai_retcode = getaddrinfo("192.168.1.5", "http", &hints, &addrs);
if (gai_retcode != 0)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "Error encountered during getaddrinfo: %s\n", gai_strerrorA(gai_retcode));
    return 1;
}
```

Let's walk through this a bit, `getaddrinfo` takes a `node` parameter - which is either a hostname string or an ip address string.

The second parameter is `service` - which is a string specifying the port to connect to, or the service being used (`http`, `https`, `telnet` etc - you can find a list of services in the [IANA port list](https://www.iana.org/assignments/port-numbers) or in `/etc/services` of your linux box).

The third parameter is *the address of an* `addrinfo` struct containing "hints" to aid in selecting the right address. For connecting to a server, you usually need to set only the `ai_family` and `ai_socktype` members, everything else should be 0 initialized (which is what the [compound initializer](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/compound_literal) does automatically). `AF_UNSPEC` on `ai_family` means "find me either ipv4 or ipv6 addresses - no particular requirement", `SOCK_STREAM` on `ai_socktype` means "find me stream servers addresses" (aka TCP servers, not Datagram servers). HTTP is a stream based protocol.

The final parameter is *the address of a pointer to an* `addrinfo` struct. This is where the results of the lookup are stored in.

`getaddrinfo` returns 0 on success and fills up the pointer to `addrs` pointer. `addrs` is now a linked list of addresses returned from the lookup - the first one in the list is directly accessible, the next one is accessible through `.ai_next` and so on until you reach `NULL`. The regular shenanigans.

For websites having multiple servers around the world, `getaddrinfo` will return many addresses. They are arranged in the most relevant way determined by your machine. That is, the first one is the address most likely to work well. But you should *ideally* try the next ones in the linked list in case the first one fails.

For non zero returns, you can use [`gai_strerror`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/ws2tcpip/nf-ws2tcpip-gai_strerrora) to print the error message. This is named `gai_strerrorA` on windows for whatever reason. There's also a `gai_strerror` on windows but it returns a `WCHAR*` as opposed to a `char*`. On linux, you'll be using `gai_strerror`, not `gai_strerrorA`. Relevant linux docs on [`gai_strerror`](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/gai_strerror.3.html)

Now that you have a list of addresses, you can create a socket and connect to one of them-

```c
int sfd = socket(addrs->ai_family, addrs->ai_socktype, addrs->ai_protocol);
if (sfd == INVALID_SOCKET)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "Error encountered in socket call: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
    return 1;
}
if ((connect(sfd, addrs->ai_addr, addrs->ai_addrlen)) == -1)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "Error encountered in socket call: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
    closesocket(sfd);
    return 1;
}
```

**NOTE**: This is only trying the first address in the linked list, if the first one fails - it just gives up. This isn't ideal for a real world usecase. But for your specific usecase, it probably won't matter.

Pretty self explanatory, [`socket`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winsock2/nf-winsock2-socket) takes the `ai_family`, `ai_socktype` and `ai_protocol` values from your `addrinfo` structure and creates a socket. It returns `INVALID_SOCKET` on failure (this is just `-1` on linux). Relevant linux docs on [`socket`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/socket.2.html).

[`connect`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winsock2/nf-winsock2-connect) takes the socket descriptor you just got from `socket`, and the `ai_addr` and `ai_addrlen` values from your `addrinfo` structure to connect to the server. It returns `SOCKET_ERROR` on failure (again, just `-1` on linux). Relevant linux docs on [`socket`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/connect.2.html).

Now all the low level socket shenanigans is done. Next comes HTTP shenanigans. To make an HTTP request, you need to know the HTTP spec, you can read the entire thing [here](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/HTTP/1.0/draft-ietf-http-v10-spec-01.html).

Just kidding, here's a more digestible version - [courtesy of MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Messages).

But basically, the format of a message is sort of like this-

```
<HTTP-VERB> <REQUEST-PATH> HTTP/<VERSION>\r\n[HEADERS-TERMINATED-WITH-CRLF]\r\n[BODY]
```

So a `GET` request to `/blah-blah/record/record.cgi` using HTTP 1.0 and no headers (no body either, since this is a `GET` request) looks like-

```
GET /blah-blah/record/record.cgi HTTP/1.0\r\n\r\n
```

Before moving on, I need to mention why I'm demonstrating `HTTP/1.0` instead of the more sensible for the times - `HTTP/1.1`. Since not all servers actually support `1.0` fully. The real difference between the 2 is that `1.1` requires a `Host:` header, and it allows keeping the connection alive - which is more efficient for multiple requests to the same server.

About the `Host:` header, if you know what hostname the server is expecting in the request header, great! Change it to `HTTP/1.1` and put the `Host: hostname` in. Where `hostname` is...well, the hostname. For all I know, your server might just be accepting `192.168.1.5` as the hostname, but it also may not.

The second part is the keep-alive connection part. A keep-alive connection gets *a bit complicated* with blocking sockets. If you decide to use a keep-alive connection and try to `recv` the response from the server, when there is nothing more to read from the stream, `recv` will keep blocking until there's something - since the connection is still alive. There are ways to solve this ofcourse, the behaviors of which vary from linux to windows. So I'd recommend just setting the `Connection` header to `close` if using `HTTP/1.1`. I assume this would be "good enough" for your usecase. The HTTP request would then look like-

```c
GET /blah-blah/record/record.cgi HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: hostname\r\nConnection: close\r\n\r\n
```

Now, to send the request-

```c
char const reqmsg[] = "GET /blah-blah/record/record.cgi HTTP/1.0\r\n\r\n";
if (send(sfd, reqmsg, sizeof reqmsg, 0) == SOCKET_ERROR)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "Error encountered in send call: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
    closesocket(sfd);
    return 1;
}
```

[`send`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winsock2/nf-winsock2-send) takes the socket descriptor, the message, and the message length and returns the number of bytes sent or `SOCKET_ERROR` on failure (`-1` on linux). Relevant docs for linux on [`send`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/send.2.html)

There's some peculiarity here that should be noted. `send` *may* send less bytes than the length of the full message. This is normal for stream sockets. When this happens, you have to send the rest by calling `send` again and starting from where `send` left off (add the return value to the message string pointer to obtain the continuation point). This is omitted for brevity but it is **highly unlikely** to actually happen for such a short message. If you have any machine from *the last decade* - `send` will send that tiny message in full.

Please don't rely on that in an actual project though.

Congrats! you've successfully sent a request to the server. Now you can receive its response. The response format is like this-

```
HTTP/<VERSION> <STATUS-CODE> <STATUS-MSG>\r\n[HEADERS-TERMINATED-WITH-CRLF]\r\n[BODY]
```

You don't have to receive if you don't want to, the data will just be sitting there in the stream buffer, which will "vanish" when you close the socket. But here's a small example on parsing out just the status code-

```c
int status;
char stats[13];
if (recv(sfd, stats, 13, 0) != 13)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "Error encountered in recv call: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
    closesocket(sfd);
    return 1;
}
sscanf(stats, "HTTP/1.0 %d ", &status);
```

[`recv`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winsock2/nf-winsock2-recv), works much like `send`, just the other way around. It fills the buffer you pass as its second parameter and the maximum number of bytes it'll read can be mentioned in its third parameter. The return value of `recv` is the number of bytes read. Relevant docs for linux on [`recv`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/recv.2.html)

The peculiarity mentioned before is present here too. `recv` may read less than the bytes you mention in the third param. But with any half decent internet connection, 13 bytes will definitely be read in one go.

Why 13 bytes? That's the length of the `HTTP/1.0` + a space + 3 digit status code + a space. We're only interested in the status code for this. `sscanf` will then parse out the status code (assuming the server responded correctly) and put it into `status`.

If you want to read any marginally large size (and/or execute multiple `recv` calls), be sure to do it in a loop and use the return value of the number of bytes read to appropriately use the buffer.

After all of this, be sure to call `freeaddrinfo` on `addrs` and `closesocket` on `sfd`.

Further reading: MS docs on [Winsock2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-s/windows/win32/winsock/windows-sockets-start-page-2)

On linux, everything is very similar - but with much less headaches :) - I recommend checking out [beej's guide to network programming](https://beej.us/guide/bgnet/pdf/bgnet_usl_c_1.pdf) if you're looking for implementing this on linux.

(In fact, it's a great read for windows programmers as well! Up to date with modern functions that support ipv4 and ipv6 seamlessly, no manual and painful struct filling etc)

Everything will be super similar, you just need to change the headers - get rid of the stupid windows specific startups and replace `WSAGetLastError` inside `fprintf` to just a regular `perror`.

Edit: Replacement for compound literal (`static struct addrinfo const hints = { .ai_family = AF_UNSPEC, .ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM };`)-

```c
struct addrinfo hints;
memset(&hints, 0, sizeof hints);
hints.ai_family = AF_UNSPEC;
hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;
```

Suffice to say, if you have access to a compiler that supports C99 and above - use compound literals instead - it's plain better :)

Comment: Thank you for your great and detailed solution. Also, should I use this line as it is? `static struct addrinfo const hints = { .ai_family = AF_UNSPEC, .ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM };
` it's giving error.

Comment: @A.k.What C version are you using? Compound literals are supported since C99. Anything before that won't work with that. I'll put an edit to mention the replacement syntax for older C versions.