# using vs2017 build live555,fatal error C1083:Cannot open include file"ifaddrs.h": No such file or directory

Tags: c++

Hi I'm using visual studio 2017 and I received that error when I compiled live555 sub-project groupsock, "fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'ifaddrs.h': No such file or directory.I don't know how to deal with the problem.How do solve this problem?thanks!
GroupsockHelper.cpp  header content

```
#include "GroupsockHelper.hh"

#if (defined(__WIN32__) || defined(_WIN32)) && !defined(__MINGW32__)
#include <time.h>
extern "C" int initializeWinsockIfNecessary();
#else
#include <stdarg.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#if !defined(_WIN32)
#include <netinet/tcp.h>
#ifdef __ANDROID_NDK__
#include <android/ndk-version.h>
#define ANDROID_OLD_NDK __NDK_MAJOR__ < 17
#endif
#endif
#include <fcntl.h>
#define initializeWinsockIfNecessary() 1
#endif
#if defined(__WIN32__) || defined(_WIN32) || defined(_QNX4)
#else
#include <signal.h>
#define USE_SIGNALS 1
#endif
#ifndef NO_GETIFADDRS
#include <ifaddrs.h>
#include <net/if.h>
#endif
#include <stdio.h>

// By default, use INADDR_ANY for the sending and receiving interfaces (IPv4 only):
ipv4AddressBits SendingInterfaceAddr = INADDR_ANY;
ipv4AddressBits ReceivingInterfaceAddr = INADDR_ANY;

static void socketErr(UsageEnvironment& env, char const* errorMsg) {
  env.setResultErrMsg(errorMsg);
}

NoReuse::NoReuse(UsageEnvironment& env)
  : fEnv(env) {
`enter code here`groupsockPriv(fEnv)->reuseFlag = 0;
}

NoReuse::~NoReuse() {
  groupsockPriv(fEnv)->reuseFlag = 1;
  reclaimGroupsockPriv(fEnv);
}
```

.......

Comment: Code? Please make this a [mcve]

Comment: Isn't `ifaddrs.h` a unix-like header, not windows?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Porting getifaddrs to Win XP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3069082/porting-getifaddrs-to-win-xp)