# C++ Get Local IP address,differentiate between the VPN and local network

Tags: c++, ip

My computer is connected to the local network(ethernet adapter) with ip address 10.3.3.3 and it is connected with my VPN(PPP adapter) with the IP address 172.4.0.70

Now, how can I get my local IP(10.3.3.3) programmatically?

I had tested using the following code.

But I can't differentiate between the VPN and local network, any help will be much appreciated.

```
 WSAData .....;

 char* address=NULL;

 getLocalIP(&address);

 int getLocalIP(char** raddr)
 {
      char ac[80];
      if (gethostname(ac, sizeof(ac)) == SOCKET_ERROR)
      {
            return 1;
      }

      struct hostent *phe = gethostbyname(ac);
      if (phe == 0)
      {
          return 1;
      }
      for (int i = 0; phe->h_addr_list[i] != 0; ++i)
      {
          struct in_addr addr;
          memcpy(&addr, phe->h_addr_list[i], sizeof(struct in_addr));

          //How can I tell if it's not VPN?

          //if (isnotVPN){

          *raddr=inet_ntoa(addr); //<== ip address

          //break;}
      }
      return 0;
 }
```

c++
VS2008
Win7 64bits

Comment: Possible duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/122208/get-the-ip-address-of-local-computer

Comment: You are looping on phe->h_addr_list[i], but if this is > 1, you will only get the last address.

Comment: What do you want to do with it? Basically whether something is VPN is implementation detail of the link layer that applications are not supposed to know or care about.

Comment: @Peter: No, it's not duplicate. This question asks for some extra information on top of that other question.

Comment: @Jan: Yup, just thought it looked very similar.  Thanks!

Comment: @Peter K: I am using the same smaple code.   :)

Comment: You can probably obtain this information from one of the IP Helper functions such as GetAdaptersInfo().

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Few years later...
Just ran into the same issue, and figured out a solution. You can use GetAdaptersInfo() to get all the local adapters, and then cycle through the list and pick the first with a valid subnet mask and a default gateway (my VPN adapter didn't have one).
If you have both WiFi and Ethernet with default gateways!!, I guess you can use the Type field to pick Ethernet..

This is similar to the sample code for GetAdaptersInfo() on MSDN.

```
PIP_ADAPTER_INFO pAdapterInfo;
PIP_ADAPTER_INFO pAdapter = NULL;
DWORD dwRetVal = 0;
PIP_ADDR_STRING pIPAddrString, pIPGwString;
ULONG ulOutBufLen;

pAdapterInfo = (IP_ADAPTER_INFO *)malloc( sizeof( IP_ADAPTER_INFO ) );
if( !pAdapterInfo ); //Malloc Failed

ulOutBufLen = sizeof( IP_ADAPTER_INFO );

if( GetAdaptersInfo( pAdapterInfo, &ulOutBufLen ) == ERROR_BUFFER_OVERFLOW ) {
    free( pAdapterInfo );
    pAdapterInfo = (IP_ADAPTER_INFO *)malloc( ulOutBufLen ); 
    if( !pAdapterInfo ); //Malloc Failed 
}

if( ( dwRetVal = GetAdaptersInfo( pAdapterInfo, &ulOutBufLen) ) == NO_ERROR ) {
    pAdapter = pAdapterInfo;
    while( pAdapter ) {
        pIPAddrString = &pAdapter->IpAddressList;
        pIPGwString = &pAdapter->GatewayList;
        while( pIPAddrString ) {
            ULONG ulIPMask, ulIPGateway;
            ulIPMask = ntohl( inet_addr( pIPAddrString->IpMask.String ) );
            ulIPGateway = ntohl( inet_addr( pIPGwString->IpAddress.String ) );

            if( !ulIPMask ) {
                pIPAddrString = pIPAddrString->Next;
                continue;
            }

            //First adapter with a default gateway
            if ( ulIPGateway ) {
                strncpy( GETYOURSTRINGHERE, pIPAddrString->IpAddress.String, sizeof(pIPAddrString->IpAddress.String));
                free( pAdapterInfo );
                return;
            }
            pIPAddrString = pIPAddrString->Next;
        }
        pAdapter = pAdapter->Next;
    }
}

if ( pAdapterInfo )
   free( pAdapterInfo );
```