# How come I am only seeing one of the inet addresses of the host with this code?

Tags: c, networking, network-programming

I just wrote this snippet:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>

int main(void)
{
    sockaddr_in self;
    hostent *he;
    char local[HOST_NAME_MAX];
    gethostname(local, sizeof(local));
    he = gethostbyname(local);

    if (he)
    {
        std::cout << "Addresses: " << std::endl;
        unsigned int i = 0;
        while(he->h_addr_list[i] != NULL)
        {
            std::cout << "\t" << i << " --> ";
            memcpy(&self.sin_addr, he->h_addr_list[i], he->h_length);
            std::cout << self.sin_addr.s_addr;
            std::cout << " ( " << inet_ntoa( *( struct in_addr*)( he-> h_addr_list[i])) << " )" << std::endl;
            i++;
        }
    }
    else
        std::cout << "gethostname failed" << std::endl;
}
```

When I run it on an example host I get something like this (i made up these addresses here though):

Addresses:
    0 --> 1307150150 ( 10.23.215.61 )

whereas if I run `ifconfig` I get much more outuput, and in particular the above address corresponds to only the first displayed interface from `ifconfig` when there are at least two more before the `eth0` ones. How come? I would have expected this to run through all of the possible network addresses in this host...

After the answer below, I did the following (using getaddrinfo):

```
int main(void)
{
    struct addrinfo *result;
    struct addrinfo *res;
    int error;

    char local[HOST_NAME_MAX];
    gethostname(local, sizeof(local));

    error = getaddrinfo(local, NULL, NULL, &result);
    if (error != 0)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "error in getaddrinfo: %s\n", gai_strerror(error));
        return 1;
    }

    for (res = result; res != NULL; res = res->ai_next)
    {
        struct in_addr addr;
        addr.s_addr = ((struct sockaddr_in *)(res->ai_addr))->sin_addr.s_addr;
        std::cout << addr.s_addr
                  << " ("
                  << inet_ntoa(addr)
                  << " )"
                  << std::endl;
    }

    freeaddrinfo(result);
}
```

I now get the same output as before..except repeated the "correct" number of times. (i.e. from ifconfig I see three interfaces from which I could presumably send from in multicast and I get the inet address of the first one repeated thrice as output of above.

Comment: Seems similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8106882/cant-obtain-local-ip-using-gethostbyname

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function `gethostname` returns the name the host has been configured with. You are free to configure *your* computer with wathever name you choose.

The function `gethostbyname` does the “normal” name resolution process for your OS. Typically it will first look into your `/etc/hosts` and failing that query your DNS resolver.

To get `gethostbyname` to return all your configured IP address you will have to either put them in your `/etc/hosts` file or ask your DNS administrator to update your server.

By the way, `gethostbyname` is deprecated in favor of [getaddrinfo](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3493#section-6).

Comment: should note that `gethostbyname` can only return IPv4 addresses.

Comment: the /etc/hosts contains only this it seems:


# Do not remove the following line, or various programs
# that require network functionality will fail.
127.0.0.1               localhost.localdomain localhost
::1             localhost6.localdomain6 localhost6

seems useless for my example

Comment: @PalaceChan Then it probably comes from your DNS. What OS are you on? Try `host <hostname>`.

Comment: Old old Linux 2.6.18 - red hat if not mistaken. I also tried getaddrinfo - results in the edit i just made to the question. Running host <hostname> shows the address both approaches above show.

Comment: @PalaceChan then it means you should ask your DNS administrator to add the other addresses you want in the DNS server.