# Platform-Independent Way to Obtain IP-Address in C++

Tags: c++, ip, platform-independent

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Get the IP Address of local computer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/122208/get-the-ip-address-of-local-computer)

I want to be able to get the IP address for the machine I'm on in C++ without querying external www.whatsmyip.com, but also want to do it in a platform-independent way. I can find specific examples for both Windows and Linux, but can't think of an easy way to do this in a platform-independent way. I would also consider options of putting an if-statement in depending on the Operating System if this seems like the best/only method.

Comment: How would you want to handle multiple IPs?

Comment: It is still unclear to me from the referenced post if there is a platform-independent way. They seem to be either Windows or Linux specific.

Comment: Considering `#ifdef` instead of `if` would be a wiser choice, if you want to do the network programming natively.

Comment: What's windows/linux specific with boost or POCO??

Comment: @Bart I need just one external IP to communicate with a worker in a general Master-Worker scheme. The IP is used to send the task communication back to the Worker.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are able to use boost, I highly recommend the [boost::asio](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/doc/html/boost_asio.html), which is about as cross-platform as you're going to get.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative to boost::asio may be the [POCO Network Library](http://pocoproject.org/slides/200-Network.pdf).

Comment: I know that Boost compiles on Blue Gene/P, but not sure about POCO. One of the systems I am working with is BGP, so I will need the included libraries to cross-compile as well.