# C++ - System findstr "FINDSTR Cannot open..."

Tags: c++

I'm trying to use a system call to print out my IP address, instead of calling a batch script. My current code is:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

void main(){
system("@echo off");
system("ipconfig | findstr /R /C:'IPv4 Address'");
system("PAUSE");
return;
}
```

However when ran I get this error "FINDSTR: Cannot open Address'". What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The effect of `@echo off` will expire when the shell exits; multiple calls to `system()` are not an effective substitute for a batch file.

Comment: Why are you using the shell and an external program for this at all, when you could just call the function that returns this information?

Comment: Does the command work when you type it into the console?  Those `'` look like they should be `"`.

Comment: @BenVoigt I couldn't find a function that returns the information.

Comment: On linux it's `getifaddrs`, on Windows see http://stackoverflow.com/a/10838854/103167

Comment: @NathanOliver If you use `"` instead of `'` then the string ends at the start of "IPv4 Address" and starts again at the end of it.

Comment: @CipheredData: You would escape it as `\"` in the C++ source code, resulting in an actual double quote character in the string sent to `system()`.  But `system()` is the wrong way to do this to begin with.

Comment: @BenVoigt Thanks. :)