# Get the real IP address of a localhost connection

Tags: sockets, network-programming

How can I check the real IP address of a connection from localhost? Basically I use the following function to get the address of a given remote connection.

```
std::string getpeerhost(int _fd) const {

  socklen_t len;
  struct sockaddr_storage addr;
  char ipstr[INET6_ADDRSTRLEN];
  //int port = -1;

  len = sizeof(addr);
  if(::getpeername(_fd, (struct sockaddr*)&addr, &len) == -1) {
    return {""};
  }

  // IP4
  if (addr.ss_family == AF_INET) {
    auto s = (struct sockaddr_in *)&addr;
    inet_ntop(AF_INET, &s->sin_addr, ipstr, sizeof(ipstr));
  }   
  // IP6
  else {
    auto s = (struct sockaddr_in6 *)&addr;
    inet_ntop(AF_INET6, &s->sin6_addr, ipstr, sizeof(ipstr));
  }   

  return std::string(ipstr);
}
```

The issue is `getpeername` might return `127.0.0.1` when the given socket file descriptor `_fd` is from the same host as the server. In my application, the server has to pass the client's address among other clients and certainly passing `127.0.0.1` doesn't make any sense.

Comment: If your machine has a static IP address just use that. If your machine is leased a DHCP address use the method described here. http://stackoverflow.com/a/10838854/2913685

Comment: If `getpeername()` returns 127.0.0.1 that's where the connection is from. There is no other remote address. If you don't want your client addresses to read 127.0.0.1, don't let them connect to it: have them use the external IP address of the host.